# Can you assign a specific number of cores to a kernel in CUDA?

Tags: concurrency, cuda, collision-detection

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 with 20 Streaming Multiprocessors. I want to port a collision detection system using CUDA which has multiple branches in the code depending on the type of objects in collision (for instance: the code for checking whether a sphere and cylinder are in collision is different than the code for checking collisions between a sphere and another sphere). To increase performance and decrease code divergence, I was thinking of running each of these branches in parallel in separate kernels since my device supports concurrent kernel execution. **Is there a way to assign a specific number of CUDA cores to each kernel in this case?**

I tried to find out how to do this on the CUDA developer guide pages and also on Stack Overflow but wasn't able to find a way to tailor which cores get assigned to which kernels.

Hope someone who has tried something similar can guide me or point me in the right direction. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: No you can't......

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't directly map a serial code(CPU code) into a GPU code(parallel code). You need to understand the basic concepts and map your problem to the parallel architecture. I would recommend you to first study parallel programming and CUDA basics before trying to port your code to GPU. Otherwise, you will probably achieve even less performance than the CPU code. For the object collision and other common parallel problems you can read these excellent online books: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-v-physics-simulation/chapter-32-broad-phase-collision-detection-cuda .

However for your question, you can run different branches in a single kernel by rounding the borders up to warp size. There will be no divergence when you have different execution paths between different warps. These warps are automatically parallelized by Cuda. You don't have to worry about which SM they run on. The following code has no divergence.

```
int idx= threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
if (idx < offset[0]) {  //offset[0] is multiple of 32
    // task number 0
}
else if (idx < offset[1]) { //offset[1] is multiple of 32
    // task number 1
}
else if (idx < offset[2]) { //offset[2] is multiple of 32
    // task number 2
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, the answer you provide seems to be just the sort of thing I was looking for! So basically if I understand this correctly, I can use these proxy if conditionals to make sure parts of my code run on different warps and are executed in sync right?

Comment: You can, but  I still think you need to learn a bit cuda before you begin with trial and error. If you don't learn Cuda and GPGPU programming, probably you will have a lot of problems and gain no performance.